# Format eventRender date in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to render events from PHP/MySQL and all is working fine.  I looked through the FullCalendar documentation and [bootstrap to achieve my popover event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).  I use the FullCalendar `eventRender` and I have access to the `event` and `element` using

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $(element).popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : true,
        trigger : 'hover',
        title : event.title + ' <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>',
        content : '<p>' + event.start + '</p><p>' + event.end + '<p>' + event.description + '</p>'
    });
```

When it shows the date (such as `event.start`) it looks like this on the front end `1485427500000` then I learned I could use the Javascript date function.  After realizing this gave me the wrong format so I tried `toLocaleTimeString()` which gave me the following results:

[image]

The first date time you see uses `new Date(event.start)` the second uses `new Date(event.end).toLocaleTimeString()`.  But there are 2 problems I can not seem to figure out.

**Question:**  How can I format both `event.start` and `event.date` to be my timezone (you notice the time is different on the calendar and on the popup) and to be something like (for example) 5:00pm Thursday Jan 26th, 2017 ?

Comment: event.start and event.date are two different things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates returned by FullCallendar are [Moment objects](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/), which means you can format them using the Moment syntax.  There are examples of format strings on the [Moment site](http://momentjs.com/).  Something like this should work for the example format you specified:

```
content: '<p>' + event.start.format('h:mm a ddd MMM Do YYYY') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting [FullCalendar v4](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3), Moment is [optional plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment-plugins).

You can use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat):

```
content: '<p>' + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
  month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false,
}).format(new Date(info.event.start))
```